# AerospikeException - Error Code 1500: LDT-Not Enabled on Namespace on lmap.put() even though ldt-enabled is set to true

Tags: java, aerospike

We have Aerospike server version 3.8.3 (which supports LDTs)

We are getting the following exception -

```
2018-08-01 16:11:31,558 1320573 [task-scheduler-3] ERROR o.s.a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler [SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:37] - Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void com.MyClassNameService.storeCurrentBalance(java.lang.String,java.util.Date)'.
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error Code 1500: /opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/ldt/lib_lmap.lua:2620 LDT-Not Enabled on Namespace
```

At this line lmap.put() -

```
Key key = new Key(aeroconf.getHistoryNamespace(), setName, owner);
        LargeMap lmap = client.getLargeMap(null, key, binName, null);
        //Some processing here..
        lmap.put(Value.get(mapKey), Value.get(monthlyScoreHistory));
```

Above is happening even though `ldt-enabled true` is set at namespace level in aerospike.conf.

Answer (score 1):

LMap were declared as deprecated in [server release 3.5.2](https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.5.2) and by 3.8.3 you only have LList remaining.

You should move to using the non-LDT [Map API](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map.html) instead. With [Aerospike database 4.2](https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#4.2.0.2) you also have an 8MB [`write-block-size`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#write-block-size) limit, which should be more than plenty, though you'll need to have enough memory on each node to handle buffering such blocks and loading those potentially very large records. It's also not a great idea from a performance perspective to have multi-MB records, but it'll definitely be higher performance than your LMap situation, so that shouldn't be a barrier to migration.